# ASP.NET MVC 4 DB First M2M create form with between table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

I try to build an webapp with ASP.NET MVC 4 DF.
Now i have a M2M relationship with an between table.
**Main Table**: Member
**Between Table**: Member_Game
**Taget Table**: Game

Now I try to create a "create" View with one Form. After the Main Table Form I need an option field with data from the target and save it to the between table.

My Problem is I have no idea how can i solve this problem.
Thanks for any help.

Edit:
My Problem is how can i save the optionfield setting to the between table :)

[DB Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilgIN.png)

Comment: Where are you stuck? Showing options field from the target or while saving it to mapping table?

Comment: Oh Sorry. By Saving :)

Comment: Your Member entity will have ICollection<Game> Games collection. Just add to this collection while saving the Member object. This will automatically create entries in mapping table.